# Are these three expressions equivalent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was doing a test problem at Khan Academy in the geometric sequence section. The problem gave an iterative function and I'm supposed to write the explicit function:

[image]

I kept on trying:

$$2.2 \cdot -5^{n-1} $$
$$2.2 \cdot -5^{(n-1)} $$
Both failed, I was tearing my hair out until I did:
$$2.2 \cdot (-5)^{n-1} $$

And it worked. Is this most likely a bug or am I confused about order of operations and fail to see that -5 needs to be in brackets? All three answers are equivalent, no?

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not equivalent.

$$2.2 \cdot -5^{n-1} = 2.2 \cdot -1 \cdot 5^{n-1}$$

The former is evaluated as $5$ to the $n-1$ power multiplied by $-1$ while the latter is $-5$ to the $n-1$ power. Remember: exponentiation is performed before multiplication.

They will have different signs when $n$ is odd:

$$-5^{3-1} = -1 \cdot 5^2 = -1 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 = -25$$
$$(-5)^{3-1} = (-5)^2 = -5 \cdot -5 = 25$$

Comment: Hmmm, strange, about the invisible -1, for me at least. Would (-5)^2 be the same as (-5^2)?

Comment: $-5^2$ means $-(5^2)$ and not $(-5)^2$.  If a mathematician means $(-5)^2$ she will probably just write $5^2$.

Comment: @GEdgar but these are the same? (-5)^3 = (-5^3) , right? Also, do you do Tex in comments the same way as in a question? \cdot \frac{4}{3}

Comment: @Zebrafish Yes, but what if you have even exponents? Then they aren't the same. In general $-a^b \neq (-a)^b$. The former is evaluated as $a^b$ then negated. The latter is repeated multiplication of $-a$...

Comment: Don't know if this helps you or not, but...  $(-5)^2=-5 \cdot-5$ and $-5^2=-1  \cdot 5 \cdot 5$  .  In my first problem the exponent was on the -5 and my second problem it was just on the 5..

Answer (score 1):

$$g(1)(-5)^{n-1}=g(1)(-5)^{(n-1)} \neq g(1).-5^{n-1}$$
Not the same answer when n is odd but 
$$g(n)=g(1)(-5)^{n-1}$$

Is the correct formula...

$$g(2)=-5g(1)$$
$$g(3)=5^2g(1)$$
$$g(4)=-5^3g(1)$$
The sign alternate between + and -